# Use Pry in gems without modifying the Gemfile or using `require`

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler, pry

I am trying to debug a gem that's used by a Rails app.

I cloned the Gem locally to go prying around (and also allows me to do nice things such as `git bisect`, etc.)

```
# Gemfile
gem "active_admin", path: "~/dev-forks/active_admin"
```

However, I am often stuck with adding Pry to a Gemfile somewhere to be able to use it, or calling `require "pry"` live in the code even though I don't want it in there. For example, I will sometimes forget about it, fix the bug, and then commit to the project with Pry in the Gemfile.

Should I not do that, a `LoadError` will arise, `cannot load such file -- pry (LoadError)`.

I have to admin I'm a bit lost between the different contexts (Rails project, Gem, local Ruby) and actual gems (Gemfile, require, installed).

How can I use `binding.pry` in a Gem within Rails, without intervention of the Gemfiles?

Comment: I have the same problem too. One technique I considered (but didn't implement) was using git hooks to check for occurrences of `pry` inside my code during commits. Then in Rails' Gemfile, add pry to the development group; in gem's, add pry to the Gemfile (not gemspec.)

Comment: Your unit tests should also fail if you have `pry` sticking around somewhere.

Answer (score 10):

Jon from the past! As you know, I have the answers to (almost) all your problems.

In this case, you're actually describing two problems: (a) you can't `require 'pry'` when Pry is not in the Gemfile, (b) you can't use Pry if you don't `require` it.

What Bundler does, as Conrad Irwin [writes](https://github.com/ConradIrwin/pry-debundle/tree/0feeea54cdc3ca8bfbd3518ad6d18fde13c226c7#long-winded-explanation):

> Bundler is an awesome gem that gives you a good degree of confidence that "if it works in development, it works in production". It can do this by being vicious about gem dependencies: if it's not in the Gemfile, it's not getting required. It also ensures that everyone's development environment is identical, no more does "it works on my machine" cut it as an excuse.
>
> There are circumstances when this dogmatic dedication to duty can get in the way. In particular all good developers have set up their development environment very personally. Obviously, it's not important that my local tools work in production, and it's positively bad for productivity if everyone is forced to have an identicial development setup.

So in doing all the good things Bundler does for us Ruby developers, it comes by design with a caveat: "what's outside the bundle/Gemfile (eg system gems) *doesn't exist anymore*." How it does that is by redefining the `require` process and changes your `PATH` so that it only sees what's in the bundle.

That means you can't use Pry at all without polluting the Gemfile, you say, right? Not so fast. Conrad Irwin being the smart little cookie that he is, came up with a solution and made [Pry Debundle](https://github.com/ConradIrwin/pry-debundle), a gem that temporarily reverses the patches Bundler made to our require.

So all you have to do is just `require 'pry-debundle'` then, right? Oh... wait. Yep, Debundle is probably not in the Gemfile.

The monkey fix is to hard copy the source of `pry-debundle.rb` to `~/debundle.rb`, and then `load` that. (For now, you'll need Pry loaded to run that source file, but you can run only the `debundle!` method to get there, require Pry, and go prying around. A little monkeypatching is needed, but I'm working on a PR.)

Comment: this is the best answer I've seen to one's own question! amazing! lol

Answer (score 2):

if you want to use and debug a gem in your rails app, then it should be in the development and test group of the Gemfile in your app.

you can use tools like pry-debugger https://github.com/nixme/pry-debugger to set breakpoints in your pry session `break SomeClass#run`.

i think it's valid to add pry to every project that i fork to fix a bug or contribute stuff. just don't put it in the `.gemspec` files.

if you are pushing `binding.pry` changes to your repo, you should add commit hooks like Jim pointed out. i don't think that this is a pry related issue, it's dependent on how much care you take when reviewing your diff before pushing it out.